# How to dequeue script on woocommerce product?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I'm trying to dequeue some scripts on woocommerce product, but for some reason I can’t find a way to check for a single product.

`is_singular('product')` doesn't work for some reason. The dequeue itself works without the checks, e.g.:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_custom_scripts', 100 );
function my_custom_scripts()
{
    wp_deregister_script( 'wp-mediaelement' );
    wp_deregister_style( 'wp-mediaelement' );
}
```

Comment: I believe it's too early to use the conditional functions in that hook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/

you can try `is_product()` its on the woocommerce docs